# Retrieve table values without retrieving duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

My table is this:

```
CLASS
5
5
6
6
6
7
8
8
8
9
10
```

Is it possible to retrieve class values 5,6,7,8,9,10 without retrieving duplicate class values?

Comment: WHY ARE WE SHOUTING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DISTINCT to achieve it.

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name;
```

Based on above syntax, your query should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLASS FROM 'table_name'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLASS FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: You could have been more specific by explaining how distinct works and displaying the syntax , before displaying the example